# Sending intent to asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask

How do I send intent to asynctask from Activity? I have 2 buttons which do very similar things in asynctask (the difference is only in postExecute method). I would like to send an intent with button's ID.

I declared an intent:

```
final Intent i = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
```

In each onClick listener I have following code:

```
i.putExtra("button", logoutButton.getId());
```

Executing asynctask:

```
myHttpClient.execute(myParams);
```

myHttpClient contains context and activity:

```
private final Context mContext;
    private final Activity act;
```

How can I take the intent values in asynctask?

Comment: You can't send an Intent to an AsyncTask.  What you could do is make a constructor in the AsyncTask that takes an int as a parameter for the button id.

Comment: Ok, I got this. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to send Intent! You can do this by adding fields to your `asyncetask` like blow:

```
String button_id;

public YOUR_ASYNCETASK_CLASS_NAME (String ID){
    button_id = ID;
}
```

And use it wherever you need.